# SwiftUI change a value in a List by tapping

Tags: swiftui

I'm struggling with something today and I can't find a nice solution for that.
I have a simple Class (User) with some attributes and other class (UsersContainer) as ObservableObject with a array of the first class:

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool
}

class UsersContainer : ObservableObject{
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    init() {
        users = [User(name: "John", isActive: true), User(name: "Paul", isActive: true), User(name: "Jack", isActive: false)]
    }
}
```

In my ContentView, I have a List where I show the name of the User and change the color and the strikethrough based if the user is active or not:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var usersContainer = UsersContainer()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List(usersContainer.users, id: \.id){user in
                Text(user.name)
                    .strikethrough(!user.isActive)
                    .foregroundColor(user.isActive ? Color.black : Color.gray)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Tap")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result on the Emulator is what I expected:

[image: screenshot from emulator]

My problem is on the TapGesture in the ContentView. I want to change the Row when the user tap the row with this code:

```
.onTapGesture {
      user.isActive.toggle()
}
```

But I'm getting a error:

Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'user' is a 'let' constant

How can I change the value of the user to a variable?

I hope I could explain my problem well.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
List(Array(usersContainer.users.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, user in
    Text(user.name)
        .strikethrough(!user.isActive)
        .foregroundColor(user.isActive ? Color.black : Color.gray)
        .onTapGesture {
           self.usersContainer.users[index].isActive.toggle() 
        }
}
```

Comment: It works!
In this case you are changing the source of the List and not the object on each row.
Is that a normal approach/best practice in this case?
Thanks

Comment: It follows single source of truth concept.

Answer (score 0):

**SwiftUI 2022**

One of the most important concepts that you must keep in mind is **Source of Truth** and how to handle that from different views within your app.

In your example, the **Source of Truth** is located in your *ContentView*. And you are trying to manipulate or mutate that **Source of Truth** from a different view down the view herarchy.

In your example, you are changing it from the TextView's onTapGesture.

```
Text(user.name)
       .strikethrough(!user.isActive)
       .foregroundColor(user.isActive ? Color.black : Color.gray)
       .onTapGesture {
           print("Tap")
           user.isActive.toggle()
       }
```

By using the property wrapper **@ObservedObject** in your *ContentView* for **UsersContainer()**, gives you the option to "Bind" this Source of Truth to other views. Meaning it will allow those views to mutate the data that belongs somewhere up in the view hierarchy and at the same time triggering a re-render of the views.

Lists now has a new API that makes biding much easier.

Your code would look something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var usersContainer = UsersContainer()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List($usersContainer.users){ $user in
                Text(user.name)
                    .strikethrough(!user.isActive)
                    .foregroundColor(user.isActive ? Color.black : Color.gray)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        user.isActive.toggle()
                        print("Tap")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The **$** prefix shows that you are passing data to a view that is allow to manipulate its source of truth.

A few keys points to take from this new code:

1. Since your 'User' conforms to identifiable, you can use List without the "id" parameter.
2. When a view that does not own the data is displaying, then use the @Binding wrapper to be able to manipulate that data up the herarchy.
3. Always keep a clear **Source of Truth**

Happy Coding!